# C# - Create an EventHandler that can take any number of parameters

Tags: c#, event-handling

I wish to create a custom EventHandler that can have any number of objects as its parameters and the objects it gets isn't known in advance.

I know I can pass it an Object[] but what I would like is something similar to

```
MyEventHandler someCustomEvent(Object obj1, Object obj2, Object obj3)
```

where the number of objects can be 0 or 10 if needed.

**EDIT:**

So thanks to the comments and answers I've got I've come to this,

```
public class FinishedEventArgs : EventArgs {
            public Object[] Args{ get; set; }
        }

protected void OnFinished(params Object[] args) {
            if(this.Finished != null) {
                this.Finished(this, new FinishedEventArgs() {
                    Args = args
                });
            }
        }
```

Does it look acceptable?

Comment: How about using `params object[] args`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out params, pretty much what I was looking for. Now how would I go about using params with the best practice that Kent wrote in his answer?

Comment: We'd probably do better solving the problem that led you to this current solution, than to try to fix this solution. I.e. this event handler definition looks suspect, so what problem is it actually solving for you? Why don't you know what objects you're going to pass to event handlers? Why do they have no better parent class than object? etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`EventHandler` is just a delegate.

You can create delegate like this:

```
public delegate void Foo(params object[] args);
```

And event:

```
public event Foo Bar;
```

You will end up with firing event like this:

```
Bar(1, "");
```

But, as @Kent Boogaart said, you should create events using `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`, so better approach would be creating class:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MyEventArgs(params object[] args)
    {
        Args = args;
    }

    public object[] Args { get; set; }
}
```

And event:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> Bar2;
```

So you will fire event like this:

```
Bar2(this, new MyEventArgs(1, ""));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it sums up everything I was looking for pretty well.

Answer (score 11):

You can define a delegate as such:

```
public delegate void MyHandler(object p1, object p2, object p3);
```

and then use it in your event definition:

```
public event MyHandler MyEvent;
```

However, this is contrary to best practices and not recommended. Instead, you should encapsulate all the extra information you require into your own `EventArgs` subclass and use that from your delegate:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    // any extra info you need can be defined as properties in this class
}

public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
```

Comment: Thank you Kent. Maybe I was a bit unclear in what I actually wanted. I would like to be able to pass either an array of objects or several objects individually and I don't know how many objects there are in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to stop you declaring a delegate that accepts a params array, the same as you would define any other method which takes multiple arguments:

```
delegate void someCustomEvent(params object[] args);

event someCustomEvent sce;
```

However, it would be unusual. As Kent says, it's more normal to follow the convention on the .Net platform of having event handlers accepting two arguments, the sender (object), and the event arguments (EventArgs, or something deriving from it).