# Raise event c# gives error: No overload matches delegate EventHandler

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates

I am trying to make an event that gets raised when something happens. So other classes that contain a reference to the class that raised the event get notified. 
This is what i have got so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DropArea : MonoBehaviour {

    public event EventHandler ObjectChange;

    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        var correctType = FindParentWithComponent(other.gameObject);
        if (correctType != null)
        {
            var cc = correctType.GetComponent<Object_properties>();
            if(cc.VariableTypeSelector == AcceptedVariableType)
            {
                DetectedObjectChange(null); // here i want to raise the event
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void DetectedObjectChange(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = ObjectChange;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e );
        }
    }  
}
```

this is the class that should get notified by the raised event:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class IfStatement : MonoBehaviour {

    public DropArea Base, Check, Increment;

    void Start()
    {
        Base.ObjectChange += OnBaseObjectChange; //this line gives me an error so i cant compile. 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnBaseObjectChange(System.Object sender)
    {
        Debug.Log("event is raised by element");
    }
}
```

this is the error i get :

> No overload for 'OnBaseObjectChange' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

I have never worked with events before but i cant really understand how to fix this. Sadly i also dont really understand the microsoft docs about events :(

If extra clarification is needed pls let me know!
All help is really appreaciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change this method. Because your event also requires `EventArgs`

```
void OnBaseObjectChange(System.Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log("event is raised by element");
}
```

Delegates hold signatures of methods. As you can see your event has a method type with two parameters. Trying to use it with a single parameter causes the error.

```
  handler(this, e);
```

---

Alternatively, you can change the type of your event to something else. For example an `Action<System.Object>` to keep the current signature of your handler method, if you don't want to have an `EventArgs` in your event:

```
public event System.Action<System.Object> ObjectChange;

void OnBaseObjectChange(System.Object sender)
{
     Debug.Log("event is raised by element");
}
```

Where you can call it like:

```
handler(this);
```

Comment: awesome this works, but is there and possiblility to give the handler different parameters? so instead of `handler(this, e)` to `handler(true)` ?

Comment: @FutureCake you can use any other class instead of `EventHandler` to have a different signature for your handler method. e.g. `Action<System.Object>`

Comment: @Bizhan could i also just not use a class?

Comment: @FutureCake why not use a class? what's wrong with classes?! just change `EventHandler` to `Action<object>`

Comment: Yes, you can. Here is an example.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994666/c-sharp-create-an-eventhandler-that-can-take-any-number-of-parameters . Actually the tricky part with events is when you call DetectedObjectChange method it checks if there is a listener of ObjectChange event. If yes, it calls the method with same signature as the delagate. So, the event raiser object indeed holds a reference of listener object. This part is very important for avoiding 'memory leaks' and 'uncollected' objects.

Comment: @Bizhan i have nothing against classes but i was just wondering :)

Comment: @FutureCake do you realize every object you use in c# is made of a class? what else do you expect to use?!

Comment: @FutureCake I updated the answer to show what I mean. please take a look.

Comment: @Bizhan awesome thanks for that! this helps a lot :)